# How do i convert a .wav file into a base64 encoded string?

Tags: java, ios, cordova, audio

Im using cordova to read/record an audio file from an iPhone. This creates a .wav file whose contents i want to convert to an encoded string to store on my data server. Any pointers on how i could do this conversion in java ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    File audioFile = new File("fileName.wav");

    byte[] bytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(audioFile);

    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);                                       
    Utilities.log("Encoded String: ", encoded);

    byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(encoded, 0);
    Utilities.log("Decoded String: ", Arrays.toString(decoded));

    try
    {
        File file2 = new File("fileName.wav");
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file2, true);
        os.write(decoded);
        os.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @meettitan Good point, he asked for Java but is using cordova so a JS solution would be using: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File